\LaTeX in headline of index
I have several indices and use package splitidx.
I endow index with headline \newindex[LaTeX packages]{pkg}.
Now I want \LaTeX instead of jut LaTeX, but then
! Undefined control sequence.
\S@12 ->\gdef \tf@size 
                       {12}\gdef \sf@size {8}\gdef \ssf@size {6}
l.211 }
     
? 

What to do???

Best provide a short compiling example showing said message …

The package splitidx uses \xdef where it should use \protected@xdef: a command such as \LaTeX doesn't survive \xdef and so you get a fatal error.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{splitidx}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%%% Fix the horrible error in splitidx.sty
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\newindex}{\xdef}{\protected@xdef}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\newindex}{\xdef}{\protected@xdef}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\newindex}{\xdef}{\protected@xdef}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\newindex}{\xdef}{\protected@xdef}{}{}
\makeatother

\newindex[\LaTeX{} packages]{pkg}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

test\sindex[pkg]{\LaTeX}

\printindex[pkg]

\end{document}


No such error with imakeidx. Note \index and not \sindex.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=pkg,title=\LaTeX{} packages]

\begin{document}

test\index[pkg]{\LaTeX}

\printindex[pkg]

\end{document}


ooh dear.. but there is a reason for using splitindex...
I shall inform the author and ask for a fix, right?

no use of upmendex possible for imakeidx?

I see: with xpatch I can fix the bug in splitidx!!! great!
